# Xamarin Studio Package Console Edit Options

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, xamarin-studio, package-managers

I'm using Xamarin Studio version 5.5.3 to build my ASP.NET MVC Application. When I create a MVC APP, is created with the version 5.2, however this version isn't totally supported and I need downgrade the package to some version < 5. I have to run the command "PM> Install-Package AspNetMvc -Version 4.0.20710" on package console, but it is readonly (as viewed on picture). 
Someone have any idea to solve this problem?

[image: Print Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Package Console that ships with Xamarin Studio currently is read-only and only shows messages from NuGet.

There is a PowerShell console available as a [separate addin](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-extensions) but it is still an alpha release.

Alternatively you can install a specific version from the Add Packages dialog by running a search for all versions of a NuGet package:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc version:*
```

This will return all versions in the Add Packages dialog and you can then pick the version you want to install.

Comment: Tks.. Works fine. I'm having some problems with references now, but it's going. =)